# What is the benefit of converting a Ktable into a Streaming before materializing it into a Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I often see this pattern in book and blogs that I read all around, but can't quite understand how useful it is:

```
Stream.GrouBy.Agg.toStream.to(Topic)
```

What is the benefit of converting the KTable into a stream before materializing its result into a topic ?

Can't we just write `Stream.GrouBy.Agg.to(Topic)`

What would be the difference in term of implications between the 2 ?

**EDIT1**

The javadoc says that `to` on a Ktable has been deprecated and that converting to a stream first and then using `to` was the recommended approach.

I wonder why ?

Comment: The reason to deprecate `KTable#to()` was to avoid confusion users. Many people did not realize that a `KTable` is a continuously updating table. For example, there was also `KTable#foreach()` that was called for each update -- but lot of people thought it would be a on-time scan over the current `KTable` content. To make the "streaming nature" explicit, the corresponding methods where deprecated.

Comment: I see make sense!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [Javadoc](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KTableImpl.java#L531) , KTable `.to()` method implementation is as given below where it calls `.toStream()` internally:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void to(final String topic) {
    to(null, null, null, topic);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void to(final Serde<K> keySerde,
                   final Serde<V> valSerde,
                   final StreamPartitioner<? super K, ? super V> partitioner,
                   final String topic) {
        this.toStream().to(keySerde, valSerde, partitioner, topic);
    }
```

There is no difference technically in both method, above one is just converting KTable into KStream internally by hiding the `.toStream()` method call, while  in     `Stream.GrouBy.Agg.toStream.to(Topic)` , it calls `.toStream()` explicitly.